# How can I get equally spaced points in a ListLogLogPlot?

Tags: plotting

I am using `ParallelTable` to generate couples `{j,fun[j]}` which then I plot with `ListLogLogPlot`, but because of the loglog scale all points pile up at the far right of the plot.

How can I get equally spaced points?

Comment: Generate points according to `{b^j,fun[b^j]}` for some `b`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`PowerRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerRange.html)

```
ListPlot[
 Transpose[{#, #}] &@PowerRange[1, 10^6]
 , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
 , FrameTicks -> Automatic
 , ScalingFunctions -> {"Log10", "Log10"}
 ]
```

[image]

Inevitably, if you Google that function, you get something else...

[image]